# mysqldump command in linux till date(I mean i dont want to dump changes in the database that i made today)

Tags: mysql, dump

Normally we Dump data in such manner:

What i require is i just want to dump data till yesterday !!!

mysqldump -u root -p gateway > dumpfilename.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass -e parameter with query that should be executed:

```
mysqldump -u root -p troy22022012 -e "SELECT * FROM gateway WHERE ..." > dumpfilename.sql
```

Comment: Thanks that worked....

tuffkid how to pass specified database name and from that table name using the same